# Scala macro Liftable with forward reference

Tags: scala, macros

I very roughly have the following code:

```
object MyObj {
  def callWithParams(params: List[Param]): String = "some string"
}

sealed trait Param
case class Single(id: Int) extends Param
case class Group(id: Int, subParams: List[Param]) extends Param

def buildMyParams(): List[Param] = List(Single(1), Group(2, List(Group(3, Single(4))))

def macroImpl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  // TODO: need a implicit Lift[Param] implementation here

  val myParams = buildMyParams()
  c.Expr[String](q"MyObj.callWithParams($myParams)")
}
```

My attempt at the implicit `List[Param]` is:

```
implicit val lift = Liftable[Param]({
  case s: Single => q"Single(${s.id})"
  case g: Group => q"Group(${g.id}, ${g.subParams})"
})
```

This doesn't compile because of the forward reference in the `Liftable` when trying to lift a `Group`, because of `Group.subParams`.

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Can you post the whole macro code? I think you simply need to use shapeless.Lazy

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - I've edited the question - does that have enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the lift as a def rather than a val was enough to fix this:

```
implicit def lift = Liftable[Param]({
  case s: Single => q"Single(${s.id})"
  case g: Group => q"Group(${g.id}, ${g.subParams})"
})
```